# How to write a Pundit policy with 3 or statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, control-flow, pundit

I have a [Pundit policy](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) that's working properly, but the way I've written it doesn't seem to be the "best" way to express this. It's a policy with three "or" statements. Here's the code:

```
def update?
  user.admin? or user.moderator? || user.id == @artist.user_id
end
```

What's another way I could write this? Or is this the best way to express this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you mix `or` and `||`? What seems to be "not the best" about `a || b || c`?

Comment: I just did that to separate it visually because admin and moderator are similar

Comment: FWIW, the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or) suggests `or` is "banned" due to the "high probability of introducing subtle bugs".

Comment: cool. thanks @jvillian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways to: either

```
def update?
  user.admin_or_moderator? || user == @artist.user
end
```

`admin_or_moderator?` is just to say, it could be even something like `privileged?` and implement this method in your `User` model. Or

```
def update?
  %i(admin moderator).include?(user.role) || user == @artist.user
end
```

Here I'm guessing you have something like a role in your `User` model but that's the idea

Comment: would it be better to put `admin_or_moderator` in the user model or as a private method on the policy?

Comment: it could makes sense even in the user model for me

Answer (score 2):

BTW, you *could* do something like:

```
delegate *%w(admin? moderator?), to: :user

def user_artist?
  user == @artist.user
end

def update?
  admin? || moderator? || user_artist?
end
```

That seems pretty clean to me.